# How to remove "-" in text Python

Tags: python, merge

```
text = '''hi guy-
     s how do i re-
      order this 
       text so it doesn-
        t have any "-" ele-
    ments and it is still i this form'''
```

I have this text and i want function that makes it to be in this form:

```
text = '''hi guys
     how do i reorder
      this 
       text so it doesnt
        have any "-" elements
    and it is still i this form'''
```

```
def uprav(text):
    zoz = ""
    text = text.split()
    print (len (text))
    for i in text:
        if i[-1] == "-":
            nove_slovo = i[:-1]
            zoz = zoz + nove_slovo 
        else:
            zoz = zoz + i+ " "
    zoz.split()
    print (zoz)

This is what i tried
```

Comment: That's not a question but a task (your homework?). Please take the Q offline and then start with the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 1):

try to use .replace() function.

> > text.replace('-', '')

Comment: That leaves the problem with the changed line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the replace method

```
text.replace('-', ' ')
```

keep in mind that replace doesn't mutate value, it will return the new string, so just put the new value to the same variable

```
text = text.replace('-', ' ')
```

and if you want it in function

```
def replace_dash(text):
    return text.replace('-', ' ')
```

and use it like this

```
text = replace_dash(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
text = '''hi guys
     how do i reorder
      this 
       text so it doesnt
        have any "-" elements
    and it is still i this form'''

yoy = text.translate({ord(i):None for i in '-'})
print(yoy)
```